# Append two values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    var descriptionInput;
    var tbl = $(document.getElementById('21.125-mrss-cont-none-content'));
    tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find("input[name$='6#if']").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                descriptionInput = $(this).val();
                $(this).val(descriptionInput);
                $(document.getElementById('__AGIM0:U:1:4:2:1:1::0:14')).val(descriptionInput);
            }
            console.log(descriptionInput);
        });

    });
});
```

The function above gets an input value from a field in a set of rows using jQuery .val()

```
var table = document.getElementById('DYN_6000-LISTSAPLMEGUI-tab');
    var t = table.rows.length;
    //getting current blank cell ID and upping the blank cell ID to the new last cell
    var new_cell_id = table.rows.item(t-1).id;
    var old_cell_id = "DYN_6000-LISTSAPLMEGUI-key-" + t;
    table.rows.item(t - 1).id = old_cell_id;
    table.rows.item(t - 1).onmouseover = function () { showItemDetailDropDown_hover(old_cell_id); };
    table.rows.item(t - 1).onmouseout = function () { showItemDetailDropDown_hover(old_cell_id); };
    table.rows.item(t - 1).onclick = function () { showItemDetailDropDown_click(old_cell_id); };
    //create new row and table
    var drop_down_height = document.getElementById('DYN_6000-LISTSAPLMEGUI-scrl').style.height;
    document.getElementById('DYN_6000-LISTSAPLMEGUI-scrl').style.height = (parseInt(drop_down_height.replace("px", "")) + 18) + "px";
    var new_row = table.insertRow(t-1);
    var new_cell = new_row.insertCell(0);
    new_row.insertCell(1);
    //set new row and cell properties
    new_row.id = new_cell_id;
    new_row.classList.add('urNoUserSelect');
    new_row.style.width = "100%";
    new_row.style.height = "18px";
    new_row.onmouseover = function () { showItemDetailDropDown_hover(new_cell_id); };
    new_row.onmouseout = function () {showItemDetailDropDown_hover(new_cell_id); };
    new_row.onclick = function () {showItemDetailDropDown_click(new_cell_id);};
    new_cell.classList.add('urIlb2I');
    new_cell.classList.add('urColorTxtStandard');

    var new_item = t;

    new_cell.innerHTML = "[ " + new_item + " ]";
    var zyx = "grid#21.125#" + row + ",2#if";

    document.getElementById(zyx).value = new_item;
    document.getElementById('__AGIM0:U:1:4:2:1:1::0:14').value = new_cell.innerHTML;
    checkButton('keyboard');
```

This JS function is part of an if else statement that checks if there is a new value in each row and adds a sequential number to a dropdown item menu below the table. My question is: How do I append or concatenate the first value (description) into the dropdown menu after the number? For example,

> [ 1 ] descriptionInput (the value)

Everything works I just don't know how to pass the jQuery function back to JS or append each value.

Comment: I don't know what is this app for, but what the hell is with this `ID's`. 

`21.125-mrss-cont-none-content`, `__AGIM0:U:1:4:2:1:1::0:14` :D

Comment: autogenerated code from years ago :(